# Trying to map the | (pipe) key

Tags: vim

I'm trying to remap the | (pipe) key to , (comma) and I tried the following

```
nnoremap | ,
```

However, this doesn't work and pressing | takes me to the start of the line.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Huh?! I came here to make that exact same mapping! Spooky coincidence... :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to escape it.

```
nnoremap \| ,
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I don't get why | has to be escaped while I can remap \ without escaping.

Comment: Another way of denoting `|` in mappings is `<bar>` (see `:help map_bar`).